# How does the Haskell compiler handle the 'where' statement?

Tags: compiler-construction, haskell, ghc

In the following function, I'm wondering if the compiler is clever enough to work out that `x` is going to remain constant, or will it compute the head of the list for every item in the list? (I'm using GHC)

```
allSame :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool 
allSame xs = all (==x) xs  where x = head xs
```

Comment: slight improvement: `allSame (x:xs) = all (==x) xs`

Comment: This is not an "optimization"; I don't see how it would make sense for x to be computed "for every item in the list"... the semantics *require* that x be 'computed' only once. AFAIK.

Comment: @newacct: actually his `allSame` works correctly (although subtly) for empty lists, whereas yours doesn't.

And yeah, the definition of "lazy evaluation" requires that x will only be computed once.  This is not required by the standard (which only specifies "non-strict"), but every existing Haskell implementation is lazy.

Comment: @luqui: Even without laziness — even if the evaluation were strict — wouldn't x still be computed only once? AFAICT this is just the semantics of `where`, and has nothing to do with laziness/non-strictness.

Comment: @ShreevastaR, the most well known non-strict strategy other than lazy evaluation is call by name, in which a variable in a where clause would be evaluated more than once.

Comment: Of course, the compiler knows that x remains constant - like any other variable in the program after the point where it is bound.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The semantics of 'where' in GHC is that a single closure will be allocated for 'x' and shared amongst all uses. A new closure, for the function (== 'x') will be generated, and the optimizer will float it out, so that it is only generated once per traversal.

To see exactly what code is generated, check the Core (e.g. via ghc-core). GHC optimizes the code to:

```
M.allSame a eq xs =
    all
      (let 
         ds =
           case xs of 
             []   -> error "bad head"
             x : _-> x
            in
          \y -> x == y
         ) xs
```

If performance is a concern, consider using vectors, as the separate traversals will fuse, removing recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I think Haskell will just evaluate what's needed: So it's looking for `x` and finds it in the `where`-clause. Then I think it computes `x` once and does the `all`.

If you want to test it, you could write a function `myall` that does a recursion like in `all (==x)`, but essentially just prints out the comparing element. So you'll see, if you get a new argument each time or if it stays just the same each time.

#### Edit:

Here's a little function to test this: `myall` just collects the first arguments and puts it in a list.

```
myall x [] = [x]
myall x xs =  x:(myall x (tail xs))

test xs = myall (x) xs where x = head xs
```

If you call `test [1,2,3]`, you will see that the result is `[1,1,1,1]`, i.e. first `x` is evaluated to `1`, after that `myall` is evaluated.